# CSS and font size proportional to text length?

Tags: css

Is it possible to achieve font effect similar to the one seen in the right column on the
http://www.athensfoodtours.com/tours/ website in the right column using pure CSS? I guess
it's not possible but want to be sure before starting creating some ugly images...

Comment: How much do you care about it being "pixel perfect"? There are ways to do this that involve smart font stacks and pixel sized spans (like `font-size:25px`) and manual letter-spacing, but it won't be absolutely perfect.

Comment: Does anything change for you if I tell you that the content will be generated with XSLT? I can use XSLT to "estimate" the dimension, I guess. But I am not sure how the algorithm would be. Perhaps I could use fixed width font, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `font-stretch` property in CSS, but sadly it is not widely supported very well.

Before you go ahead and make images, there are a couple of jQuery plugins which might be worth taking a look at: [Stretch](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stretch) and [TextFill](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextFill)

Comment: Nice. I hoped I could somehow avoid using jQuery. But thank you for the valuable links...

Comment: TextFill looks to be the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Some of these answers call for stretching type. That's a huge no-no if you have any consideration for typeface designs. ;)

What the example is doing visually is scaling the type proportionally until it fits a particular width.

You can't do this with CSS, but you could with JS.

You'd put each line in a div set to something like inline-block so you can grab it's width. You'd then grab the width, compare it to what it should be, then increase or decrease the font size by some unit of measurement, recheck the size, and repeat until it matches your target width.

It's an interesting question/challenge. If no one has given you a working example in the next few hours, I'll try and come back and whip something up.

Comment: actually...it looks like uncollected found the answer for you with the 'TextFill' plugin. Give him/her the answer credit!

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically, but you could manually set the `font-stretch` style for each line. I'm not sure how widely supported the tag is, but here's the W3C specification for that style:

[CSS Font Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) - Section 3.3

Possible usage...

`{font-weight: ultra-condensed | extra-condensed | condensed | semi-condensed | normal | semi-expanded | expanded | extra-expanded | ultra-expanded}`

Answer (score 0):

They are images, it is achieved like so;

```
a span {text-indent: -9999px;}
```

Each a has an id assigned to it an a background imaged placed, then on hover changes the background-position like so.

```
#somelink:hover {background-position: 0 20px;}
```

You can tell they are images, look at the *five point* link the S is slightly cut off, sloppy design there!

Comment: Seems like you did not get the essence of the question? :) I asked how to achieve the same effect achieved there with images without images.